# Select files from two lists that meet one condition

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists of file names:

**1.** The first list contains file paths for one year with time steps every 5 minutes, I have come to this list after selecting only the hours I am interested in.
Each file is composed by the year 2011, the day that is correlative goes from 001 to 365 and the hour 0235.

```
A = ['20110010235', '20110011340', '20110020140', '20110020315',
     '20110020320', '20110021245', '20110021420', '20110021425', 
     '20110030220', '20110030225', '20110030400', '20110031325', 
     '20110031330', '20110040125', '20110040130', '20110040305', 
     '20110041230', '20110041235', '20110041410', '20110050210', 
     '20110051315', '20110060255', '20110061220', '20110061355', 
     '20110061400', '20110070155', '20110070200', '20110070335', 
     '20110071300', '20110071305', '20110071440', '20110080240', 
     '20110080245', '20110081210', '20110081345', '20110090145', 
     '20110090325', '20110091250', '20110091430', '20110100230', 
     '20110100405', '20110101330', '20110101335', '20110110130', 
     '20110110135', ..., '20113651325']
```

**2.** The second list contains file paths of an ERA-5 product, in this list I have, files that I have selected during the same year '2011', but these files have a time step of 1 hour.

```
B = ['201101010000', '201101010100', '201101010200', '201101010300',
     '201101010400', '201101010500', '201101010600', '201101010700',
     '201101010800', '201101010900', '201101011000', '201101011100', 
     '201101011200', '201101011300', '201101011400', '201101011500', 
     '201101011600', '201101011700', '201101011800', '201101011900', 
     '201101012000', '201101012100', '201101012200', '201101012300',
     ..., '201112312300']
```

Each file is composed of the year 2011, the days ranging from 1 to 31 or depending on the days you have each month unlike the previous list that are correlative. and the hours ranging from 0000 to 2300, every hour.

I face the following problem, I have to select from the second list, the file that belongs to the same day and the file with the closest time.
For example, if in the first list I have the file `20110010235`, I would have to select from the second list the file with the closest time, in this case it would be `'201101010300'`, and for the next file in the first list `'20110011340'` I would have to select from the second list the file `'201101011400'`, this way I would have to go through both lists until the end of the year of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, so long as you can sort the two lists.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def cnvrt_AtoTime(val):
    yr = int(val[0:4])
    dy = int(val[4:7])
    hr = int(val[7:9])
    mn = int(val[9:])
    tv = datetime(yr, 1, 1, hr,mn)
    if dy > 1:
        tv = tv + timedelta(days= dy-1)
    return tv


def cnvrt_BtoTime(val):
    yr = int(val[0:4])
    mth = int(val[4:6])
    dy = int(val[6:8])
    hr = int(val[8:10])
    mn = int(val[10:])
    return datetime(yr, mth, dy, hr, mn)

def match_files(a_list,b_list):
    a_list.sort()
    b_list.sort()
    bptr = 1
    aptr = 0
    out_list = []
    while aptr < len(a_list) and bptr <len(b_list):
        atme = cnvrt_AtoTime(a_list[aptr])
        btlst = cnvrt_BtoTime(b_list[bptr-1])
        btnxt = cnvrt_BtoTime(b_list[bptr])
        if btnxt >= atme:
            kn = btnxt - atme
            kl = btlst - atme
            if abs(kl) < abs(kn):
                out_list.append((a_list[aptr], b_list[bptr-1]))
                bptr += 1
                aptr += 1
            else:
                out_list.append((a_list[aptr],b_list[bptr]))
                bptr += 2
                aptr += 1
        else:
            bptr += 1
            
    return out_list
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the truth is I'm developing several algorithms and I had not had to face this kind of problems with files from different sources and make them coincide by dates and time, I was working on another solution different from yours, but yours is simpler, thanks.